# Safari bug (?) with floating elements?

Tags: html, css, safari, css-float

I traced a weird problem with a layout I'm working on to this compact code example which misrenders in desktop Safari. The div#shim is apparently what's triggering the browser to misrender the text. Anyone seen this before or know a fix?

```
<div id=shim style="float: left; height: 3px; outline: thin solid blue;"></div>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; width:50%; height: 50px; outline: thin solid red;">50%</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; width:10%; height: 50px; outline: thin solid red;">10%</div>

Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug.
```

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Comment: Hi, am I right in assuming that you want the text to flow under both the 50% and 10% elements if it is too long to just sit between them? Note: The problem is also seen on IOS Safari (tested on iPad IOS14).)

Comment: My goal is actually to make the shim taller, so the red rectangle floats in the middle of the page, but the first line of text that crosses the vertical barrier tends to be miscalculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've played with this in a few different ways (word break, adding divs, etc), and it looks like Safari's behavior when laying out a line next to a float is to first examine the left float at the *top* of the text line *only*, to calculate the width of the line. This conflicts with the wider float at the *bottom* of the line.
If it drew it where it calculated it, you would see the bottom of the text drawn over the lower float.
But since when it draws it, it does put the left edge at the rightmost float on the line correctly, it pushes it off the right side of the screen; sometimes it even starts there. The same principle is seen with shapeOutside as a regular box.

Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all show correct calculation, they take the floats height of the line into account. So I'm going to have to interpret this as a bug in text calculation within Safari that has no design or CSS workaround -- doesn't matter what you're doing, if the body text happens to cross a boundary between two floats where the lower one is wider, the line's going to be too long or even, if the lower float is 100% width, start off under the scroll bar.

```
<div style="float:left; clear: left; width: 50px; height: 0.3em; background: red;"></div>
<div style="float:left; clear: both; width: 100px; height: 0.3em; background: green;"></div>
<div style="float:left; clear: left; width: 25px; height: 0.3em; background: blue;"></div>
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What seem to be confusing things are the clear settings in the two floated divs.

Strangely they seem to be having a counter-intuitive effect. In Safari, the first line of the text flows into the right floated div (and continues for an amount equal to the total width).

Removing these clears seems to cure the problem.

Assuming that actually you do want the whole lot cleared before anything else is shown, this snippet puts a clear: both after the text (and shows some more text afterwards just to prove it is indeed cleared).

Tested on iPad IOS14 Safari where it seems to work whether with text too short to flow under the floated divs or with text so long that it flows under them after filling the space between them.

```html
<div id=shim style="float: left; height: 3px; outline: thin solid blue;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width:50%; height: 50px; outline: thin solid red;">50%</div>
<div style="float: right; width:10%; height: 50px; outline: thin solid red;">10%</div>

Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug. 
Here is some text to show the bug.
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
This is some stuff coming afterwards to show that it clears both the text and the red bordered divs no matter what the length of the text between those divs is.
```

Comment: Unfortunately now the shim is not a shim, it just hangs there...I want the 50% to be lower. (3px is not important but it's much larger in my layout).